# Persist console commands across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, automated-tests

So here's a rough idea of what I'd like to do:

For example:

**Step 1:**

1. Land on my site
2. Fill search bar
3. Press search

**Step 2:**

1. Land on search results
2. Click first returned item

**Step 3:**

1. Select Size/Options
2. Add product to basket

*And so on....*

I can split these out into individual steps, but that requires me to manually enter these into the console.

Is there a way I can enter all of my code (maybe check for URL changes between steps since I know the exact URLs) and continue to run the commands, rather than it stopping after the first page change?

Thanks!

Comment: chrome console?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve console to clean between pages with this setting:

[image]

Comment: that's not what I'm after.  I want my JS to continue running on page 2, 3, 4 etc... without any manual intervention

Comment: do you have SPA application? If not - then it's impossible

Comment: I've seen it done.  But I guess just not in the console.